# Problems with custom routing and child paths

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I'm working on a short url application and I'm running into a problem with child paths. Essentially what this does is save shortened URLs to a database which then translates into the full path when called by the user.

The user will typically call the short URL by typing
    http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}

which will be translated on the back end as
    http://companyServer/SomePath/ChildPath1/....

The MVC application allows users to create their own short URLs and has two ActionResults to administer this (CreateShorty & ViewShortys).

The end result should be that the user should be able to type in the following URLs and be redirected correctly.

```
http://companyServer/{actionName}
http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}
http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}?{optionalParameters}

http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}/{childUrlPath}
http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}/{childUrlPath}?{optionalParameters}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can do all except for the last two. If I attempt to add child parameters the first rout to be hit when viewing an action like create or view is 
    http://companyServer/{actionName}
it then goes on to hit
    http://companyServer/{shortUrlName}/{childUrlPath} which blocks me getting to my action methods.

Any help in this would be appreciated as I'm rather new to MVC.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Different MVC engines will handle the /1/2/3 differently. This comes down to how they read that URL. Normally it would be something like this:
SITE_URL/CONTROLLER/METHOD/KEY/VALUE

I would suggest checking the documentation to confirm. To fix it most likely means either overriding the default behaviour. Or writing exceptions before it tries to match the "Route" so to speak.

Comment: I'm usingj MVC 4 for this.